# How can I fix small image size issue in Chrome (only Facebook website)?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, chrome-for-android, facebook

Firstly I know StackExchange have a similar question. But I'm unable to comment on that question due to low reputation.

Coming to my issue Chrome browser showing images in small sizes since last week. I have tried clearing cache, site settings and also tried clearing all my chrome data from settings-apps menu. I'm using updated Chrome browser (v62.0.3202.84) and my phone model is Moto X Pure (Nougat 7.0 updated)

[image: The same post in Chrome and Firefox browsers respectivly]